# Change Django Authentication Backend for Testing

Tags: django, unit-testing, ldap

My Django site uses the LDAP backend for authentication in production, but this is not suitable for testing (impossible to create requests from dummy users). How can I disable this backend, solely for tests?

Here is the relevant settings.py section:

```
    AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
#'crowd.backend.CrowdBackend',
# 'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    )
   AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://ldap.cablelabs.com"
   import ldap
   from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch

   AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = "CN=CableLabs  Internal,OU=cabletest,OU=Teamwork,OU=community,DC=cablelabs,DC=com"
   AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "UAq,0@ki"
   AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("ou=community,dc=cablelabs,dc=com",ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(sAMAccountName=%(user)s)")
   AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {"first_name": "givenName", "last_name": "sn","username":"sAMAccountName","email":"mail","photo":"thumbnailPhoto"} 
   AUTH_LDAP_CONNECTION_OPTIONS = {
     ldap.OPT_REFERRALS: 0
   }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create an alternative settings file, for example `myproj/test_settings.py`, and specify that settings file when running unit tests.

Write the alternative settings file like this:

```
from myproj.settings import *

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        #'your.ldap.backend',
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
        )
```

That is, the settings inherits everything from your regular settings, but overrides the `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` definition, with your LDAP backend commented out.

Then, run your tests like this:

```
python manage.py test --settings=myproj.test_settings
```

Answer (score 19):

If you only need/want to disable the backend for certain tests, you can also use the [`override_settings`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#django.test.override_settings) decorator. You can use this decorator on the test case class:

```
from django.test.utils import override_settings

@override_settings(AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS=
                   ('django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',))
class FooTest(TestCase):

    def test_bar(self):
        pass
```

But you can also selectively use it on a test method:

```
from django.test.utils import override_settings

class FooTest(TestCase):

    @override_settings(AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS=
                       ('django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',))
    def test_bar(self):
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, another option to look into for testing is to change the `is_authenticated` property of the `User` object to a lambda. For example:

```
user = User(...)
user.is_authenticated = lambda: True
```